# Line breaks for array echo

Tags: php

I have a group of checkboxes in an array that I am echoing the values for. However, I am having trouble trying to get the format that I want the data to be displayed in

Right now the texts is printed as

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I am trying to get the format to three columns

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

This is the code I am using

```
form ex:
<input class='8' value="1" type="checkbox" id='Form_test8_4' name='Form_test[]'/>
<input class='8' value="2" type="checkbox" id='Form_test8_4' name='Form_test[]'/>
<input class='8' value="3" type="checkbox" id='Form_test8_4' name='Form_test[]'/>
<input class='8' value="4" type="checkbox" id='Form_test8_4' name='Form_test[]'/>


Code:
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['Form_test'])){
        foreach($_POST['Form_test'] as $check){
            echo $check;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: No, this can't be your actual code. if you were really outputting html breaks after each value, you wouldn't get them all on a single line.

Comment: And you haven't closed any input tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['Form_test']); ++$i) {
  echo $_POST['Form_test'][$i];
  if (($i + i) % 3 === 0) {
    echo '<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do. Thank you